# Apache Spark 3.4.1 version with hudi 0.11.0 version slowness

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, hadoop, java-8, hoodie

I am using spark , hudi and hadoop & java8 , AWS S3  in my project.

In my spark jobs , I was using spark 2.4.5 version,  hadoop 2.9.1 version with apache-hudi-0.8.0 version and wrote data on S3 path of AWS.
Recently I upgraded to latest version of Spark 3.x.
i.e. I moved all my spark jobs to spark 3.x version , with hadoop 3 version hence tried with  hudi 0.8.0, 0.11.0 , 0.14.0 but jobs are damns slow in reading and writing on existing S3 file paths data.

Are there any settings I need to change  in Job ?
There seems to be some issues with library/jar compatibility though  the job does not throw any error or exception or warning .

How to fix this slowness problem ? Any help in this regard is highly thankful.